# How to load a lot of files from assets asynchronously?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-assets

I know that it has similar topics. But in each topic we are open `InputStream` before task will be run and in new thread load data. But I have 90 asset files. Is this a single way to create 90 `AsyncTask`? Can I get access to main thread in `inBackground()` method to get assets and open new `InputStream`? Just in my case if I'll create 90 tasks I also need to synchronize their order of launch and finish. I need a point of synchronization where my `AsyncTask` will be wait the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to have a Service with a ThreadPool executor and do your loading there, you can have a bunch of threads running in parallel to do your reading. When you are done you call back into your activity, you could use a broadcast, or a binder interface with a callback.

Another option is to have a fragment with setRetaininstance(true) and do it there with either AsyncTasks or a thread pool executor.

But do not do it in the activity with async tasks, if the user rotates the device you will have potentially 90 tasks running and no activity to return the results to.

Comment: Thank you! I agreed it's best way! But I need app only to show on presentation. So, device will not rotated (it's desktop). It's main for me to finish it as quickly as it can. I have a bit of time before presentation.

Comment: I think that can use `publishProgress` where in `onUpdateProgress` open new `InputStream` and in `inBackground` check some flag. I know it's a hack but I cannot find better from the fastest ways

Comment: Of course, it's very dirty way to check flag in infinity loop but works stable :)